# Procedure or function xxxxx has too many arguments specified

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

My stored procedure is as follows :

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp5]
    @mat NVARCHAR(1000) = NULL,
    @party NVARCHAR(1000) = NULL,
    @place NVARCHAR(1000) = NULL,
    @truk NVARCHAR(1000) = NULL,
    @qty NVARCHAR(10) = NULL,
    @ptm NVARCHAR(10) = NULL,
    @mop NVARCHAR(100) = NULL,
    @tos NVARCHAR(100) = NULL,
    @driver NVARCHAR(100) = NULL,
    @date1 DATE = NULL
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(4000); 
    DECLARE @params NVARCHAR(4000); 
    DECLARE @rate nvarchar(10); 

    SET @sql ='select  @rate = ['+@mat+']   from tblcos'+ ' where [Name] = @party' 
    set @params = '@party nvarchar (1000), @rate NVARCHAR(10) OUTPUT'  
    exec sp_executesql @sql, @params,@party= @party,@rate = @rate OUTPUT

    INSERT INTO tblsls([Party], [Place], [truk], [Material], [Qty], rate, 
                       [Payment], [MOP], [TOS], [driver], [Date]) 
        SELECT 
            @party, @place, @truk, @mat, @qty, @rate, 
            @ptm, @mop, @tos, @driver, @date1
END
```

aspx.cs code file is as follows :

```
namespace crusoft
{
    public partial class WebForm3 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["VRAConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs);

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp5", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date1", SqlDbType.Date).Value = Calendar1.SelectedDate.ToShortDateString();
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@party", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Ddprt.SelectedValue;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@place", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = tbpls.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@truk", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Tbtru.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mat", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Ddmat.SelectedValue;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@qty", SqlDbType.SmallInt).Value = Tbqty.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@rate", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 10);
            cmd.Parameters["@rate"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ptm", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Tbptm.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mop", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Ddmop.SelectedValue;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tos", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Ddtos.SelectedValue;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@driver", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Tbdri.Text;

            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the program it fails, when I execute without the `@rate` parameter, everything works fine, but I want to execute with the `@rate` parameter.

I am sure the stored procedure is working correctly.

Comment: The error message is pretty self explanatory, you're trying to add 11 parameters when the proc only takes 10.

Comment: Your `sp5` stored procedure does not receive any parameter named `rate`.

Comment: your procedure has no parameter named @rate !!!!

Comment: *"but I want to execute with @rate parameter"* - Then change your stored procedure to *have* a `@rate` parameter.

Comment: i am trying add 11 parameters ,and my proc can take 11 , i am sure i had not done any mistakes there

Comment: no i cant , because i declared the value @rate

Comment: `@rate` needs to be a parameter, not just an variable that is internal to the procedure. It also needs to be marked as `OUTPUT`.

Answer (score -1):

Include @rate as an output parameter in the procedure and the code should be fine